# I need to compare the elements of 2 vectors JAVA

Tags: java, methods, vector, compare, operator-keyword

I need to compare the elements of 2 vectors but it keeps throwing an exception. Please help, Im wondering if Im doing wrong comparisons since vectors use methods.

```
 for (int i=0; i <= vect.size(); i++)
          {
              if (i >0 && i <= vect.size())
              {     
                if( vect.get(i) == vect.get(i--) ) //EXCEPTION HERE
                {
                     vect2.add(vect.get(i)+ "");
                }else{vect2.add(vect.get(i++));}

              }                  
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

Never change the value of `i` in a `for-loop`!

Replace `i--` by `i-1` and `i++` by `i+1` and adapt your conditions on `i` to check the correct range of values.

Comment: But but... I see everyone do that all the time: for(int i=...; i>=0; --i) { }. Don't tell me thats *wrong*.

Comment: No this is perfectly. What is not is doing: ``for(int i = ...) { i++ }``

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

```
for (int i=0; i <= vect.size(); i++)
                 ↑
```

Second problem will arise when you change this to `<` because you still have `vect.get(i++)`.

You need to be careful with indexes, since arrays are *zero-based*, and `Vector`s *backed up by an array* internally, indexes run between [0, size-1].